# Matching primary key and foreign key value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to match the value of column `[LESSONCAM_ID]` in both tables `TBL_LESSONCAM` and `TBL_VIDEO` as shown below.

`[LESSONCAM_ID] in TBL_LESSONCAM` is the **Primary Key**

`[LESSONCAM_ID] in TBL_VIDEO` is the **Foreign Key**

---

```
TBL_LESSONCAM
╔══════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ LESSONCAM_ID ║ LESSONID ║    CAM     ║ VIDEOPATH ║
╠══════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║          100 ║       10 ║ Audience 1 ║ C://...   ║
║          101 ║       10 ║ Audience 2 ║ C://...   ║
║          102 ║       10 ║ Lecturer   ║ C://...   ║
╚══════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

---

```
TBL_VIDEO (BEFORE UPDATE)
╔═════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ANALYSIS_ID ║ LESSONID ║ TIMESTAMP ║  VIDEO  ║ LESSONCAM  ║ LESSONCAM_ID ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║           9 ║       10 ║       300 ║ C://... ║ Audience 1 ║ NULL         ║
║          10 ║       10 ║       600 ║ C://... ║ Audience 2 ║ NULL         ║
║          11 ║       10 ║       900 ║ C://... ║ Lecturer   ║ NULL         ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝

TBL_VIDEO (AFTER UPDATE)
╔═════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ANALYSIS_ID ║ LESSONID ║ TIMESTAMP ║  VIDEO  ║ LESSONCAM  ║ LESSONCAM_ID ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║           9 ║       10 ║       300 ║ C://... ║ Audience 1 ║ 100          ║
║          10 ║       10 ║       600 ║ C://... ║ Audience 2 ║ 101          ║
║          11 ║       10 ║       900 ║ C://... ║ Lecturer   ║ 102          ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

---

I have attempted the following update statement for `TBL_VIDEO` at the end of my code, but it won't update and still remain `NULL`:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd8 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE v SET v.LESSONCAM_ID=lc.LESSONCAM_ID FROM TBL_VIDEO v JOIN TBL_LESSONCAM lc ON v.LESSONCAM_ID=lc.LESSONCAM_ID; ", conn)) {
   using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd8.ExecuteReader()) {
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Table design is wrong.For insert/update/delete use ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform `JOIN` on `TBL_LESSONCAM.CAM = TBL_VIDEO.LESSONCAM`

OR `lc.CAM = v.LESSONCAM`

Comment: Meaning change the line "JOIN TBL_LESSONCAM lc" to "TBL_LESSONCAM.CAM = TBL_VIDEO.LESSONCAM"?

Comment: @waffles1313 just replace v.LESSONCAM_ID=lc.LESSONCAM_ID with lc.CAM = v.LESSONCAM